# On Using the UCRDTW Package for Time Series Clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I have pip-installed this package for time series mining but there is zero documentation about how to use it. Which methods can I use to perform my analysis? Does anyone use this package?

https://pypi.org/project/ucrdtw/

Comment: I don't know anything  about this package, but how about tsfresh https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ? It has documentation and is quite popular for time series

Comment: Thank you, it looks like an interesting package although I don’t see functionality related to DTW and clustering

Comment: For clustering you can use it to generate features from your time series and then use other packages for clustering. For DTW I have found this, it may suit your needs https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dtw.html ?

Comment: Thank you, I’m loving tsfresh. I’m having a bit of trouble scaling with tslearn but it’s actually a pretty good library